# Possible to set `foldexpr` using a function reference?

Tags: functions

Got this:

```
let Func = function(folding_function) "folding_function is name of function
setlocal foldexpr=call(Func(v:lnum))
```

This is so user can set a custom function for folding in their config file. I can't get it to work, though.

Also tried:

`call(Func, v:lnum)`

and

`call(Func, 'v:lnum')`

**Code in context**

```
" Set settings which are local to a window. In a new tab they would be reset to
" Vim defaults. So we enforce our settings here when the cursor enters a
" Vimwiki buffer.
function! s:set_windowlocal_options()
  if !&diff   " if Vim is currently in diff mode, don't interfere with its folding
    let foldmethod = vimwiki#vars#get_global('folding')
    if foldmethod =~? '^expr.*'
      setlocal foldmethod=expr
      let custom = vimwiki#vars#get_global('custom_fold_func')
      if custom
        let Func = function('VimwikiFoldLevelCustom')
        setlocal foldexpr=Func(v:lnum)
"        setlocal foldexpr=VimwikiFoldLevelCustom(v:lnum)
      else
        setlocal foldexpr=VimwikiFoldLevel(v:lnum)
      endif
      setlocal foldtext=VimwikiFoldText()
    elseif foldmethod =~? '^list.*' || foldmethod =~? '^lists.*'
      setlocal foldmethod=expr
      setlocal foldexpr=VimwikiFoldListLevel(v:lnum)
      setlocal foldtext=VimwikiFoldText()
    elseif foldmethod =~? '^syntax.*'
      setlocal foldmethod=syntax
      setlocal foldtext=VimwikiFoldText()
    elseif foldmethod =~? '^custom.*'
      " do nothing
    else
      setlocal foldmethod=manual
      normal! zE
    endif
  endif

  if vimwiki#vars#get_global('conceallevel') && exists("+conceallevel")
    let &conceallevel = vimwiki#vars#get_global('conceallevel')
  endif

  if vimwiki#vars#get_global('auto_chdir')
    exe 'lcd' vimwiki#vars#get_wikilocal('path')
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: try `Func(v:lnum)`

Comment: with or without `call`?

Comment: without call, don't need it.

Comment: Hmm, no dice. Also tried to simplify things: ```let Func = function('VimwikiFoldLevelCustom')
        setlocal foldexpr=Func(v:lnum)
```

Comment: If I do `setlocal foldexpr=VimwikiFoldLevelCustom(v:lnum)` without the function reference it works fine.

Comment: Check the answer, might be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, was going to play with it in a bit.

Comment: Frustrating. I have tried to get this working but the function call to `Func` just gets ignored. No idea what's going on.

Comment: I just posted the entire function for some context. Not sure that it makes any difference. But the commented out line works. The line above it does not.

Comment: try `let g:Func = function('VimwikiFoldLevelCustom')`

Comment: Yes! That did the trick. I didn't even know you could have global functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the `foldexpr` option is evaluated to get the foldlevel of a line. You don't need to add extra `call` to it. You can copy following code in a new file and source it to check how it works.

```
" vim:set foldmethod=expr noexpandtab:

function! FoldingFunction(lnum)
  return getline(v:lnum)[0]==#"\t"
endfunction
let Func = function('FoldingFunction') "FoldingFunction is name of function
setlocal foldexpr=Func(v:lnum)

finish

    fold
    fold
    fold
    fold
    fold
```

**update**

Your code doesn't work because your `Func` is a function local variable, change it to `g:Func` fix the problem.